# Setting the mydomain login page url in Scratch org via SFDX or CCI

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, cumulusci

I'm trying to build out a scratch org definition/ cci project and I'm wanting to set the sidebar URL of the main login screen,  you set that in the My Domain page, however it doesn't appear to be stored in the mydomain metadata.

Setting it in the dev org and retrieving all changes from org via
`cci task run retrieve_changes --org dev`  does not seem fetch it

So that makes me wonder if it is accessible via command line at all, if so where can one set it?